# How to run current mails from MacBook and access or search old mails from an external hard drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, mail.app, email, storage

I have a large number of emails on my MacBook Air. I want to shift all my old mails into an external hard drive and delete the same from my MacBook to save space (47 GB). Then I would like to continue with my existing accounts to keep receiving fresh or current emails.

How do I then access or search the old mails from the external hard drive and if necessary reply or download content from them?

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach.

First of all, show hidden files on your Mac by typing, on Terminal, the following command (substitute 'NO' to 'YES' if you want to re-hide files).:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Relaunch the Finder. Now, go to *youraccount/Library/Mail*, then enter the folder V*x*, where *x* is a number corresponding to your Mail version.
Then, if you have an IMAP account (i.e., Gmail), enter the imap folder.

[image]

Accessing  all the listed folders, you can see all your emails, with extension *.emlx*. If you double-click on it, it will be opened a Mail windows, where you can read the email and perform any operation you want.

[image]

You can just copy the mails you are interested in a new folder, in your external drive, and open from there when you want, for example, to read or reply to one of them.